# What is the relationship between EM radiation and Current Usage?

Tags: power, electromagnetism, physics, wave, electromagnetic

I would like to find out what is the relationship between the EM radiation an electronic device emits, and the amount of current it uses.

**So basically the relationship between: Hertz & Decibel vs. Ampere & Volt**

We know from the law of conservation of energy, that the amount of energy that goes into the system is the same that it goes out of the system. Now discounting the amount of energy that is transformed into heat via some resistance, **I would like to know how much Watts of current does an `A` hertz wave with a `B` Decibel strength does it need?**

Comment: There often isn't one.

Comment: No such thing as watts of current. There are watts per volt of current of course.

Comment: Decibel is not a unit of strength. In fact, it's not a physical unit at all. Read the wikipedia article. While you're on wikipedia, read the EMI article, too.

Comment: "discounting the amount of energy that is transformed into heat" is almost never a sensible thing to do.

Comment: Are you asking about unintended EM radiation or are you asking about the relationship between current in and power output of an RF transmitter?

Comment: @JohnD I am asking how much minimum current is necessary in order to create a EM wave with a specified frequency and amplitude.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am not technically referring to EMI, that is a passive effect. I am interested in the basics of the issue. How much power do you need to create an EM wave of an arbitrary frequency and amplitude? You need to add energy to sustain an electromagnetic field. The question is how much?

Comment: Electromagnetic radiation IS energy! P = P :) Don't believe me? Try an old crystal AM-reciever, they transform the energy from the radio waves into sound that you can hear without batteries. Cool huh?

Comment: @user1890202 ok, but I just want to quantify it. I believe the dBm unit of measurement is what I was searching for.

Comment: dBm is for quantifying transmitted and received signals, not a measure of the actual EM radiation since the received signal will vary depending on antenna types, antenna position etc.

Comment: @user1890202 but it's a broad definition. It is the maximum energy the device emits, so the RF radiation will be a subset of that. So if a device is shielded for that level, that means that it's guaranteed to not leak information out?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Build a faraday cage?

Comment: @user1890202 no I would just like to know what is the maximum emission rate or transmission rate of an electronic device in relationship to how much power in consumes.

Comment: "Transmission rate"? Do you want to send data?

Comment: @user1890202 no i want to know how much EM radiation a device emits in relationship to how much current it takes in. For instance, if you have a phone that takes 9 watts of power when it makes a call, so the radiation it emits while it is making the call is maximum **39.5424 dBm - the inefficiency**, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: First: Watts of current = bad math. Second: 1W of DC power gets you 1W*efficiency worth of RF power irrespective of frequency.

A common unit of RF power is dBm, not dB ([dB is a ratiometric prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel), like kilo or milli, it has no real *physical* meaning by itself, it needs a unit like dBV, dBm, dBW, dBA aka deci-Bels Acoustic, not deci-Bels Amp).

The "m" in dBm stands for "milliwatts" (and it's a logrithmic scale) so 0dBm is 1mW, -30dBm is 1/1000 of a mW while +30dBm is 1000mW or just 1 watt (3dB is a 2x change, 6dB is 4x and 10dB is a 10x change in power).

Now there are times when you make a measurement that includes both power and frequency. A common example is when you are interested in the "*noise power*" of an amplifier as this is often expressed in dBc/Hz, but this is a normalized unit that really means power/bandwidth. So a -30dBc/Hz noise power means you will have a signal ("c" or "carrier") that is 30dB stronger (1000x) than your noise if you have a bandwidth of 1Hz (or the noise is 30dB weaker than your signal either way). It also means your noise will be equal in strength to your signal if you have a bandwidth of *1000Hz* (and -30dBc/Hz noise as a 1000x change is 30dB and means your noise is 0dBc/**k**Hz or equal to your signal). E.g. If you want to know the thermal noise power in a 1 kHz bandwidth it's simply -174dBm/Hz (thermal noise floor) + 30dBHz = -144 dBm of noise. (addition in a dB scale is equivalent to multiplication on a normal scale)

Now 1 volt times 1 amp = 1 watt and if you had an amplifier with infinite bandwidth (impossible) and 100% efficiency (especially impossible) then 1 watt of DC power in would *always* equal 1 watt of RF power out irrespective of frequency (assuming you also had infinite *gain*, but that's a whole other can o' worms).

Having said that, higher frequency amplifiers tend to be less efficient, not because of some fundamental 1st principle relationship, but because it's harder to build good switches and amps for higher frequencies, you need fast transistors and building fast transistors is hard. Plus most materials get more lossy at higher frequencies (there's a reason why microwave ovens run at 2.45**G**Hz as opposed to 2.45**M**Hz).

I think you may have the RF world confused with the acoustic world where there *really IS* a relationship between power, frequency and perceived amplitude, but that's because for low notes you need to move more *air* to generate those long wavelength thumps and that needs more power while ear-splitting shrills have such tiny acoustic wavelengths that your speaker has to barely move to blow out your eardrums.

Now of course this is all just off the top of my head, so there may be the odd syntactical error somewhere, but you get the idea.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer, thanks. I was confused, need to read up more on **dBm**, I was looking for an absolute measurement value of RF radiation related to the power consumption. I believe this is.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of EMI radiation which a product emits has **nothing** to do with how much power it consumes.

EMI radiation has everything to do with what the product is and **if** the electronics emit EMI radiation and if they do how well it is shielded and/or absorbed in the product.

So the relationship you seek **does not exist**.

Comment: Well the power has to come from somewhere. Are you saying to me that a small RFID chip with low power can emit the same frequency and amplitude signals as a cell phone tower? I doubt it. So there must be some kind of correlation.

Comment: @user138887 The issue is that you are not correctly asking the question.  EM is a function of field (V) and flux (I), so yes, a small RFID chip can put out the same frequency and field as a cell phone tower, but with lower flux.

Comment: *Are you saying to me that a small RFID chip with low power can emit the same frequency and amplitude signals as a cell phone tower?* Yes it can be, if you allow me to **hack** the cell phone tower. You're all focused on power while the power is irrelevant. What is relevant is how the power is used in the device.